# How should I support localization for my project with Laravel with Vue using Inertia?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, localization, inertiajs

I am intermediate in Laravel. I have some published projects in Laravel for my clients.

I started a Project with **Laravel with Vue** using Inertia. I **used a starter kit of Laravel 10 with the breeze and vue**. While I am setting up my project and configuring various things, I walked through the `lang` directory which I **published by artisan command by Laravel 10**.

I am stuck at localization. I knew how to translate and localize things with Laravel only. Here is Laravel with vue is absolutely new to me.

I researched for implementing localization but I found 3 to 4 years old resources without proper implementations and a lot of hard work even lack of some translation features of laravel.

As I stated I used the starter kit and I publish the lang directory using the artisan command. I tried to change the `failed` message of the `auth.php` file located in `lang/en/auth.php`. I *checked it by entering the wrong credential* and it's appeared my updated message in error. However now I created the `hi` directory for the Indian HINDI language. I copied the `auth.php` and translated all three messages for this file. I **changed the default locale** from `config/app.php` and *tested again with the wrong credentials*. This time it does not show my HINDI translation. It is showing the same English translation again. Even again I tried to change the translation line in English and it showed the updated line.

I inspected those file components for locating the translation source and I realize that it just showed an error message by `form`. I don't know why it not picking up my translation files when I changed the default locale.

I am looking for an easier and more efficient way for localization in **Laravel with Vue and Inertia**.

After a lot of research, I found this package https://github.com/rmariuzzo/Laravel-JS-Localization.

Please let me know if will it do the job in an efficient way or if there is something default in **Laravel with Vue and Inertia** that is hidden from my eyes.

Thanks

Abhishek Kumar

Comment: You will have to provide the lang files at a public place, because as you are aware, laravel transaltes everything server side. 
The library you mentioned seems a bit old, what about this one: https://github.com/xiCO2k/laravel-vue-i18n

Comment: @Aless55 Thanks for the suggestion for the new Library. I tried it but have not found any method or way to change the `Locale`. Also, this is not getting the `locale` of Laravel. When I manually change the hardcoded `locale` in the `app.blade.php` file's `lang` attribute in the `html` tag then it shows translated values. I just need a way to change the `locale` via Vue Template.

Comment: You can pass the locale of your backend to your frontend.

Comment: @Aless55 Thanks I have done it already. It's working perfect now.

Comment: you did not post your solution yet :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how you can do localization in this case:

1. inside the `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` add

```
'locale' => function () {
     return app()->getLocale();
            }
```

2. Install the `laravel-vue-i18n` package using `npm i laravel-vue-i18n` and import it into the component where you need. for example: `import { trans } from 'laravel-vue-i18n';`
3. In the same component, where you imported the `trans`, you can use it like this:

```
{{ trans('My Profile')}}
```

4. In the component where you change your language (you probably have a change language dropdown), add this:

```
export default {
    setup() {
    methods: {
        changeLang(lang) {
            Inertia.get(route("language", lang));
            location.reload();
        },
    },
```

5.add new `en.json` or `hindi.json` files for each language.
these file should contain all the strings you are using for translations. for example:

```
{
    "My Profile": "some hindi text",
}
```

6. add a route for your language change event"

```
Route::get('language/{language}', function ($language) {
        session()->put('locale', $language);
        return;
    })->name('language');
```

Now after clicking on change language dropdown, the defined string will be changed.

I have a running and working example, if you faced any problem.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I have solved it already. I have found a more efficient way and will post my answer soon after testing on the production level.

Comment: I am glad you found a solution.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar, what is the more efficient way you were talking about?